# What is this visual directory navigator called in linux?

Tags: linux, file-management

at mark 0:56

from http://blip.tv/bogdan-vatra/necessitas-qt-suite-for-android-platform-4819643

I remember dos used to have that kind of file system navigation too. wondering if it exists for linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That interface is "[midnight commander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_commander)" (you can see it says "mc", the command, in the console title - it's a very well known old-school file management app. I used to use a similar system called FileMaven (IIRC). The console itself looks like Yakuake to me.

mc and yakuake are most likely in your distros standard repos.